# How to display JSON nested array in ember templates using handlebars

Tags: json, ember.js, handlebars.js

#### my json api from server is

```
{  
   taxonomies:[  
      {  
         id:2,
         name:"Brand",
         root:{  
            id:2,
            name:"Brand",
            pretty_name:"Brand",
            permalink:"brand",
            parent_id:null,
            taxonomy_id:2,
            taxons:[  
               {  
                  id:8,
                  name:"Ruby",
                  pretty_name:"Brand -> Ruby",
                  permalink:"brand/ruby",
                  parent_id:2,
                  taxonomy_id:2
               },
               {  
                  id:9,
                  name:"Apache",
                  pretty_name:"Brand -> Apache",
                  permalink:"brand/apache",
                  parent_id:2,
                  taxonomy_id:2
               },
               {  
                  id:10,
                  name:"Spree",
                  pretty_name:"Brand -> Spree",
                  permalink:"brand/spree",
                  parent_id:2,
                  taxonomy_id:2
               },
               {  
                  id:11,
                  name:"Rails",
                  pretty_name:"Brand -> Rails",
                  permalink:"brand/rails",
                  parent_id:2,
                  taxonomy_id:2
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and i want to display taxons -> pretty_name in my handlebars template

#### {{#each}} only show bullets but not the data

I dont know how to loop over the array.
`{{taxonomy.root.taxons.firstObject.pretty_name}}` displays the name but only the first object of each taxon and not all of them

```
<ul>
{{#each taxonomy in controller}}
{{#each}}
<li>{{taxonomy.root.taxons.pretty_name}}</li>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

How can I get the data?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in emberjs.jsbin.com ? But just a guess. the second each should look like {{#each taxonomy.root.taxons}} and inside that print using {{pretty_name}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON does not conform to Ember's JSON Conventions as descbribed at http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/ and in more details at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html.  This means your options are:

1. Change your JSON API to return JSON consistent with the Ember Data conventions
2. Write your own `Adapter` that extends `DS.RESTAdapter` that reads your JSON as listed above

For Option 1, just modify your server to return JSON that adheres to the conventions above.  If this is possible for you, this is usually the easiest method.

For Option 2, you'll want to define a new adapter either on a per-model basis, or for the entire application.  Then, you'll want to override this function: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray

See the sample code they have on that link for how to do this.

Comment: I am already using RESTAdapter and the data is successfully coming from server which i can see in ember inspector in browser.
The prob is just that i am not getting how to display it in ember template

Comment: Yes, the default RESTAdapter handles both fetching the data AND serializing it.  So you need to customize those portions of the RESTAdapter which are responsible for serialization.